# Why does [ work but not [[ in mutate while looking up a value (dplyr in R)?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a named vector which is essentially a lookup table. So the names of each element represent the key, while the element represents a value.

I have a data frame which contains a random sample of the key values which appear in the vector above. My intention is to match the key and obtain the value for each key.

It is easy to accomplish by using *mutate* from the *dplyr* package. However, in the lookup process, I get an error if I try to use *[[* instead of *[*. My understanding is that for vectors both the functions should return back a vector.

Can someone please explain why this happens? A minimum reproducible example is below.

```
x <- c("1" = "a", "2" = "b", "3" = "c")
df <- data.frame(
  k = sample(c(1, 2, 3), 10, replace = TRUE),
  v = rnorm(10)
)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
df %>%
  mutate(k2 = x[k])
#>    k          v k2
#> 1  1 -0.7502716  a
#> 2  1 -0.4002250  a
#> 3  1  0.4878860  a
#> 4  2  1.2878120  b
#> 5  3  0.6410854  c
#> 6  3 -0.6821807  c
#> 7  1  1.4106239  a
#> 8  3  0.9909921  c
#> 9  2  0.3808955  b
#> 10 3  1.6117826  c
df %>%
  mutate(k2 = x[[k]])
#> Error in x[[k]]: attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Comment: It is because you used a different operator for assignment inside the data.frame `k <- ` instead of `k=` or `v=`

Comment: With `x[[i]]`, `i` should have length of one, as explained by the error. Also, yeah, your columns have gibberish names for the reason akrun mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `[` instead of `[[` as @Frank mentioned about difference in `length` of input argument it takes (`[[` - works with length of 1 while `[` works for 1 or more) and  match the names of 'x' by converting the 'k' to `character` class and get the values from 'x' to create 'k2' (assuming that we want the values for matching names and not based on numeric index)

```
df %>%         
    mutate(k2 =  x[as.character(k)])
```

Comment: I'm sorry - I intended to use = and not <-. I will be editing the question - I guess the answer will be because of the simple reason @Frank mentioned above.

Comment: @radmuzom  Yes, `[[` would work only for length 1, and along with that, the 'k' is numeric index.  If you want to match with the names of 'x' which is character, it should be 'character

Comment: Thanks. Can you please edit your answer? It is no longer appropriate after the question edit.